# jquery limit adding partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I think his is very simple, but I do not know why the code do not work.

I am dynamically adding textboxes in my view using partial view, but I want to add restrictions for the number of rows to be added. Below is my code but it does not limit the number of rows to be added.

Kindly help, thanks in advance.

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script>
    $("#btnAdd").on('click', function () {
        var counter = 0;

        if (counter > 5) {
            alert("Limit Exceeds");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: '/Employee/Add'
            }).success(function (partialView) {
                $('#Add > tbody').append("<tr>" + partialView + "</tr>");
            });
        }

        counter++;
    });

    function deleteRow() {
        var par = $(this).parent().parent();
        par.remove();
    };
    $("#Add").on("click", ".BtnRemove", deleteRow);
</script> }
```

Comment: The problem is, `counter` is always set to `0` every time `btnAdd` is clicked, so that's why your code always gets to the `else` block.

Comment: @ekad I added an option in my solution to decrease the counter by one if you want to still be able to add rows if one has been deleted to bring the counter value below 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the variable global scope and if you want to decrease the count when you delete a row you can decrease the counter by one when you delete it.

```
var counter = 0;//<-- give the variable global scope

$("#btnAdd").on('click', function () {


        if (counter > 5) {
            alert("Limit Exceeds");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: '/Employee/Add'
            }).success(function (partialView) {
                $('#Add > tbody').append("<tr>" + partialView + "</tr>");
            });
        }

        counter++;
    });

    function deleteRow() {
        var par = $(this).parent().parent();
        par.remove();

        //Remove comment to decrease counter by one
        //counter--;

    };
    $("#Add").on("click", ".BtnRemove", deleteRow);
```